# Kill a child shell process but send 0 response code to parent

Tags: linux, shell, kill

Looking into one python project which is created to setup one very large remote cluster for enterprise (currently no resume/idempotent capability is supported).

While running python script if at any point shell/ssh command hangs I want to run that command manually and after successful completion I want to kill hanged child process.
Parent process will continue only if it get successful response code from child (can not edit python script code).

Sample code:

```
import subprocess

try:
    response = subprocess.run(["sleep 300;"], shell=True)
    print('return code: ' + str(response.returncode))
    response.check_returncode()
    print('Command completed successfully.')
except Exception as e:
    print('Error occoured: ' + str(e))
```

Kill child:

```
% ps -ef | grep sleep
  501  6904  6719   0 11:45AM ttys006    0:00.03 python@3.8/.../Python bash_sleep.py
  501  6905  6904   0 11:45AM ttys006    0:00.00 sleep 300
% kill -15 6905
```

Final response:

```
% python3 bash_sleep.py
return code: -15
Error occoured: Command '['sleep 300;']' died with <Signals.SIGTERM: 15>.
```

Is there any way I can kill child shell process but send 0 response code to python process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t do this with `kill`, but if you can attach a debugger you can use that to exit the hung process “nicely”:

```
$ python3 bash_sleep.py
```

In another terminal ...

```
$ gdb --pid ${the sleep pid}
>>> call exit(0)
>>> quit
```

This will cause the target process to exit, returning 0 to its parent. It will also invoke any exit handlers registered with the C library.